# NSString cutting one string to pieces

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsstring, foundation

So, I am making an item class to my project and I want to have keywords to search it in my search tab, I read that you can't put arrays to coreData, so I thought I put a string and seperate keywords with ,

So how would I read that string then and cut it to smaller pieces? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at NSString's `-componentsSeparatedByString:` and `-componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:` methods.

Comment: Great! Just what I wanted, I was looking at the reference, but this didn't catch my eye. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. You can go the other way, too, using NSArray's `-componentsJoinedByString:` method.